# ASP.NET 4 registry changes

Tags: asp.net, registry

While monitoring our production servers for unauthorized changes I have noticed that the following registry key changes regularly.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ASP.NET_4.0.30319\Names
```

Can anybody give me some insight into why this value keeps changing?

Regards,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick debugging shows that the values matches active process ids related to asp.net (w3wp.exe and aspnet_state.exe). I don't know what the base64 encoded key represents, but the value changes can be explained by changing processor ids (recycling, reboots, etc)