# Why would a VB.net 4.0 framework app (standard EXE) try to write to an ASP.net registry key in HKLM?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I've written a .net 4.0 framework app (in VB.net). It's a simple thing really, basically just a screensaver with a few bells and whistles.

It DOES use the webclient functions of .net to make queries to various sites on the internet, however.

But it IS NOT a web application. It doesn't run under ASP, or, as far as I can tell, have ANYTHING to do with ASP.net.

However, when I run it on a machine with Comodo Firewall installed, I get warning popups from Comodo indicating that

1) the program is trying to access the internet (this is a good thing, no problem here).

but

2) That the program is trying to create registry keys like:
hklm\system\controlset001\services\asp.net_4.0.30319\names{somelonghexvalue}

Now, I've always followed the rule that basically the only things that muck around in HKLM are installers, but here this app is trying to do something in there. And it's coming from the .net framework, my app isn't requesting any key at all from the registry.

I'm guessing that it's something that the framework has been given permission to do, even if the current user would not have rights to create keys in HKLM (since I get no errors, even when the app runs under credentials with very few rights).

So, my question is, anyone run into this before, or have any idea as to why the framework would be creating ASP.Net reg keys when running a standard EXE that doesn't have anything to do with ASP.net?

I did turn up this question, 
[ASP.NET 4 registry changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745304/asp-net-4-registry-changes)
but the asker in that case was actually dealing with ASP.net applications. In this case, I'm not.

--EDIT--
Added the code used to perform the HTTP Get, for Clara

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(requestUri), HttpWebRequest)
Dim resultPage As String = String.Empty
Using httpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Using responseStream As Stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
        Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
            resultPage = reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I'm not buying yet.  controlset001 is a *backup* of the last known good value of ControlSet.  The one that the OS can use when a boot fails.  Writing to it would be a Really Bad Idea, bad enough to mistrust your tools.

Comment: That's what surprised me about it. But Comodo firewall is flagging it as suspicious behavior and says it's coming from my application. The app itself is basically just a screensaver that monitors any Media player that's currently running, and if it finds one, queries a few image search engines to pull an assortment of images related to the current track. Nothing particularly peculiar there. Just HTTP Get requests.

Comment: I think it may be down to how those HTTP Get requests are coded - any chance of showing us the code? There are elements of the framework that can be used in forms apps that use reg keys as if they were ASP.NET

Comment: Sure, but there's nothing particularly peculiar about it (at least not that I can see). Since it's tough to put code in comments, I'll update the question above...

Comment: Did you try to debug your application step-by-step? At which point does the registry write happen? You als can step through the .Net sources to see when it happens.

Comment: It's just making a simple HTTP get request as above. In the end, I gave up and just set Comodo to ignore that particular app. At some point, i may revisit this problem, though.

Comment: Just to add some more info. 
controlset001 isn't necessarily a backup. CurrentControlSet is an alternating symbolic link to either ControlSet001 or ControlSet002. So sometimes ControlSet002 is the backup and CurrentControlSet is a pointer to ControlSet001 and sometimes it the opposite is true and CurrentControlSet points to ControlSet002.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's updating the ASP.NET performance counters for some reason, although I'm not sure why.

That registry key stores the named pipe name for  ASP.NET:

> Pipe names. One per each running worker process. See “What happens at
>   runtime?”. This sub-key appears only on the 32 bit versioned keys.
>
> ...
>
> During runtime, whenever a web application is run and the worker
>   process starts, it loads webengine.dll (or webengine4.dll in .Net
>   4.0). This library, among other many things, will initialize the performance counters local storage in the process. It will also create
>   a named pipe to which clients will be able to connect and read the
>   counters data from. The name of the pipe is stored in the
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_x.x.xxxxx\Names
>   registry key, so clients can find it.
>
> The processing of the named pipe is asynchronous. The library uses an
>   IO completion thread from the CLR, which wakes up every time

References:

[ASP.NET Internals - Performance counters implementation details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josere/archive/2010/06/18/asp-net-internals-performance-counters-implementation-details.aspx)

Comment: Interesting. Still not sure why this particular app would be cause the framework to want to monitor ASP named pipes, but that does appear to be what's going on. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'd have to profile it to know for sure, but I'd suspect that HttpWebRequest is calling an internal system.web function that initializes the counters.